# Changing parent's trap handler in child bash process

Tags: bash, signals, child-process, bash-trap

I have a bash function which is invoked as a child process (though backticks) from by bash script. Is there any way to have this function (running in the child process) modify the *parent's* trap handlers? This function creates a temporary file which I would like to be cleaned up when the parent exits. As an example

```
function get_roe_dir() {
    tmp_dir=`mktemp -d`
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        # some processing on $tmp_dir
        echo "$tmp_dir"
        # Add "rm -rf $tmp_dir" to parent's EXIT trap
    fi
}
```

Then, in the calling script, I have something like:

```
roe_dir=`get_roe_dir`
# Some processing using files in $roe_dir.
```

Once this script exits, I'd like `$roe_dir` to get deleted (using the EXIT trap). Any ideas for clean ways to achieve this?

I cannot add an EXIT trap to the `get_roe_dir()` function because it is executed in a sub-shell to capture the output. Therefore, as soon as `get_roe_dir()` has returned, the subshell exits and the EXIT trap is called, deleting the temporary directory it created.

Comment: No, there's no way to modify anything in the parent's environment.

Comment: Not really understand what you want. Why you didn't set the trap handler in the `get_roe_dir`? Post more precise question (fragment of both scripts - parent/child).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe don't understand corectly, but the next works:

```
set_trap() {
    trap "rm -rf $roe_dir" 0
}

get_roe_dir() {
    dir=$(mktemp -d /tmp/roe.XXXXXX) && echo $dir && return 0
    return 1
}

roe_dir=$(get_roe_dir) && set_trap
ls -la "$roe_dir"
echo going to exit - check ls -l $roe_dir should not exists
```

Comment: I will try to clarify the question above, but I was wanting `get_roe_dir` to set the trap. Your example works, but it relies on the caller of the function to also call `set_trap()`, which is what I was hoping to avoid. Thanks!

Comment: What you want is impossible. The child CANT modify the parent.